# X509Certificate2 chain verify(validation) in c#

Tags: c#, .net, validation, verify, x509certificate2

I have three certificates and need to verify them with each other.
1 root certificate and 2 leaf certificate.

Trying with this code block:

```
        bool retVal = false;

        X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();

        chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(rootCertificate.X509);

        chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

        retVal = chain.Build(leafCertificate.X509);

        return retVal;
```

Im getting always false. Cannot find any different way on internet.

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add untrusted certificate(s) to the chain you need to validate with the *AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority* flag.
Try to add this

```
chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;
```

before you call `chain.Build()`.